# jquery elements id is not changing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a web-site project now. I have 3 div's. if you click on any 1 of those it will take 80% space in width, the thing works but for some reason 1 of them isn't working until i change oneclose to oneopen in 3d script row, which is not right as far as i see, it does not make any sense.
The scheme it is working is next: i have different markup for *open and *close ids, when i click on one of div it changes as you can see below. does anyone knows what's going on here?

```
<script>

$('#twoclose').click(function() {
$('#twoclose').prop('id', 'twoopen');
$('#oneopen').prop('id', 'oneclose');
$('#threeopen').prop('id', 'threeclose');

});
</script>

<script>
$('#threeс').click(function() {
$('#threeс').prop('id', 'threeopen');
$('#oneopen').prop('id', 'oneclose');
$('#twoopen').prop('id', 'twoclose');

});
</script>

<script>
$('#oneclose').click(function() {
$('#oneclose').prop('id', 'oneopen');
$('#threeopen').prop('id', 'threeclose');
$('#twoopen').prop('id', 'twoclose');

});
</script>
```

Comment: make NO sense to change ids When you bind the event, you are binding it to the element, not the id... So when you change the ids, the events do not get bound to different elements

Comment: Please clarify your question. A man does not understand a thing.

Comment: @NikxDa https://solomia-gera.github.io/
check it out while i try to rethink my question, it's live at that URL

Comment: Live URL with NSFW content....

Comment: You should really not be changing the ID attribute. You should toggle a class on them.... perhaps toggling a "wide" class on and off.

Comment: @MichaelGregoire i've tried classes but the flex-basis is not working, which is actualy the main thing i'm having for that feature

Comment: @r.hrytskiv Then there has to be something else going on. All you should have to do is toggle one class on and off on each of the, I'm guessing, siblings. Without any HTML or CSS to look at, it's hard to say what might be catching you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind an event, it is bound to that element. When you change the id, the events do not automatically change. Use classes to change the styles, not ids.

Simplify your code so you do not have to hardcode ids.

```js
$(".box").on("click", function () {
   $(".box.active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.box {display: inline-block; width: 100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid black;}
.box.active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been able to get some great results after inspecting your snippet!